# Calculate Difference between time in Teradata

Tags: sql, time, timestamp, teradata

I want to take difference of 2 date fields but both are varchar field

SyntaxEditor Code Snippet :

```
start_time- 2018-03-02 06:31:22

end_time -  2018-03-02 06:33:32.478000
```

I want the result in integer as 2 in min always  and it should be an integer always

> Result :- 2

It would be very great if anyone can help to achieve my case.

Thanks

Comment: You can convert your varchar values to type Datetime, then use DATEDIFF() with parameter of minutes to find the difference, if this is sql server we are talking about. Please add what software you are using for SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize interval calculations like `cast((cast(end_time as timestamp) - cast(start_time as timestamp) minute(4)) as int)`, but it will fail for > 9999 minutes.

This is SQL UDF for calculating the difference of timestamps in seconds without limitations:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION TimeStamp_Diff_Seconds
(
   ts1 TIMESTAMP(6)
  ,ts2 TIMESTAMP(6)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,6)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN
(CAST((CAST(ts2 AS DATE)- CAST(ts1 AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 60*60*24)
      + ((EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM ts1)) * 60*60)
      + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts1)) * 60)
      +  (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts1))
;
```

If you can't create UDFs you can copy the source and apply a final `/ 60` and cast it as integer.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth for the result